# How to merge ActiveRecord_Associations with Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to merge a collection of Objects of type ActiveRecord_Associations with others objects in an array.

Here is the piece of code that I'm working :

```
#Get all projects with the same tag of current project
related_projects = current_team.projects.select{
        |project| project.tag_group_id == current_project.tag_group_id && project.id != current_project.id }

#Get all relats of type release in the related projects
related_release_relats =  related_projects.flat_map{ |project| project.relats
        .find_all { |relat| relat.relat_type == 'release' } }
```

Is it possible to do something like that ?

I'm trying to merge the current project relats with the related_release_relats( this is all relats from the others projects related )

```
relats = current_project.relats
relats.merge(related_release_relats)
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: Please explain a little further what you are expecting from the merge?  ie. is there to be any pruning of similar data? Might also help to know what type of data is stored in the arrays

Comment: @grail I'm trying to merge the current project relats with the related_release_relats( this is all relats from the others projects related )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am not 100% clear on your database structure other than what I can glean from your post, I have made some assumptions here.

Given this structure

```
 class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :projects
 end

 class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :tag_group
    has_many :relats
 end

 class TagGroup < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :projects
 end

 class Relats < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
 end
```

We can build a few `scopes` (for convenience and re-usability) to put all this work on the database side of things

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :team
    belongs_to :tag_group
    has_many :relats
    # find projects related to a given project
    scope :related_to,->(project) do 
        # uses Rails 5 .not
        # alternative Rails < 5
        # where("tag_group_id =? and id != ?",project.tag_group_id, project.id)
        where(tag_group_id: project.tag_group_id).where.not(id: project.id)
    end
  end
end
class Relats < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :project
    # only Relats that are released
    scope :released,-> {where(relat_type: 'released')}
end
```

Then we will build a small service Object to consolidate this logic

```
class RelatedRelatFinder
  def initialize(current_project,current_team)
    @current_project = current_project
    @current_team = current_team
  end

  # method to retrieve the current_project#relats and 
  # all the current_teams released relats related to the current_project
  def find_all_relats
    # uses Rails 5 .or
    # alternative Rails < 5
    # where("relats.id IN(?) OR relats.id IN(?)",
    #        @current_project.relats.to_sql,
    #        released_related_relats.to_sql)
    Relat.where(id: @current_project.relats)
        .or(Relat.where(id: released_related_relats))
  end

  private

  # This is the method for getting the current_teams released 
  # relats related to the current_project
    def released_related_relats
      Relat.released.merge(
          @current_team.projects.merge(
              Project.related_to(@current_project)
          )
      )
    end
end
```

Then usage is as simple as:

```
relat_finder = RelatedRelatFinder.new(current_project,current_team)
relat_finder.find_all_relats
```

and this will generate a SQL query similar to:

```
SELECT relats.* 
FROM relats 
WHERE 
  (relats.id IN (
    SELECT relats.id 
    FROM relats 
    WHERE 
    relats.project_id = 1 #current_project.id
  ) OR 
  relats.id IN (
      SELECT relats.id 
      FROM relats 
      INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = relats.project_id 
      WHERE 
        relats.relat_type = 'released' 
        AND projects.team_id = 1 #current_team.id
        AND projects.tag_group_id = 1 #current_project.tag_group_id
        AND (projects.id != 1) # not current_project.id
    )
  )
```

Which seems to be what you are asking for. Now the code is more understandable, more organized, there are no intermediate `Array` being created and the Database is providing all the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `merge` method for arrays but you can add arrays together.

```
current_project.relats + release_relats
```

If you want to ensure you don't include the same relats multiple times use `uniq`...

```
(current_project.relats + release_relats).uniq
```

If you want an `ActiveRecord_Relation` you can do...

```
Relat.where(id: (current_project.relats + release_relats).map(&:id))
```

Comment: current_project.relats + release_relats will return an array instead of  an active record relation.

Comment: ok, see edited answer as to how to get an ActiveRecord_Relation

Comment: Thank you @SteveTurczyn ! Just one more thing, is it possible to return also a CollectionProxy instead of ActiveRecord Relation ?

Comment: @BrunoCastro this cannot be a CollectionProxy, the reason being is that there is not a single `@owner` and a single `@target` in this case, you have `project.relats` which is a valid `CollectionProxy` where as `projects` is the `@owner` and `relats` is the `@target` but then you also want `relats` that do not belong to `project` which means they have a different `@owner` and thus the best you can get is a `Relation`.  I did however post an answer that might help clean up implementation and avoid the intermediate arrays